# Bash get variable at shell execution

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

There is a method to get a variable with the bash execution command?

**Example:**

```
./exec.sh var1 var2
```

or with arguments

```
./exec.sh -x var1 -y var2
```

I looked for "Get variable at bash execution" but nothing.

Comment: You can get by $1, $2, etc... for first, second, ... arguments.

Comment: Also look for bash getopts for named arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment mentions, $1, $2, etc are positional variables for the arguments.  But there are lots more, very useful ones too like $# for the number of arguments passed, etc.  More info at

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars